# Does agGrid support both hierarchy and master-detail in combination?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I want a grid that can show hierarchical tree structure and for the last node on each branch I would like the possibility to show a detail-view. I have tried to make this work with DevExtreme but has not made it yet. Will agGrid be a better option?

As said I have tried without any luck. And as the documention in agGrid says:

### Master / Detail is not supported with Tree Data. This is because the concept of tree data conflicts with Master / Detail, in that in tree data, any row can expand to show child rows, which would result in a clash when a row has child rows in addition to having Master / Detail at the same row.

It seems like this is not possible with agGrid either. But has someone found a creative solution to omit the problem and made a solution that can give something good enough?